# Show/Hide onClick button not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, show-hide

Hey guys I have searched for many answers and none of them seem to be working so I am going to put my code here and hopefully you can help me figure this out.

I am going to have two buttons. The first button (show_Chappie) is going to show the hidden contents and another button (hide_Chappie) and hides it self when clicked.

The second button (hide_chappie) is going to hide the contents and bring back the first button (show_chappie). The hide_chappie button itself would also be hidden.

The information div is already hidden from the start. I did this on the CSS using the display:none;

Here's my HTML code so far:

```
<button class ="show_chappie" onclick="showInfo()">Show More</button>
<div class="info">Info here.</div>
<button class ="hide_chappie" onclick="hideInfo()">Show Less</button>
```

Here's my JavaScript code so far:

```
function showInfo(){

                document.getElementById('chappie_info').style.display = "inline-block";
                document.getElementById('show_chappie').style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById('hide_chappie').style.display = "inline-block";

            }
```

I haven't written the code for the hide_chappie button because I wanted to see this working first.

So where have I gone wrong here? Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to get the elements by `id` while they have a `class`, you should change the elements `class` to `id` like this:

```
<button id="show_chappie" onclick="showInfo()">Show More</button>
<div id="info">Info here.</div>
<button id="hide_chappie" onclick="hideInfo()">Show Less</button>
```

Comment: Oh right i see. What if i use getElementByClass? would that work?

Comment: I've got it working! That was such a dumb mistake, thanks for your help. :)

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` (note the added `s`) works too on modern browsers! See http://caniuse.com/#feat=getelementsbyclassname

Answer (score 1):

you should change your code to:

```
<button id ="show_chappie" onclick="showInfo()" >Show More</button>
<div class="info">Info here.</div>
<button id= "hide_chappie" onclick="showInfo()">Show Less</button>
```

if you want to use class here,you should change your Javascript Code to

```
function showInfo(){

                document.getElementByClass('chappie_info')[0].style.display = "inline-block";
                document.getElementByClass('show_chappie')[0].style.display = "none";
                document.getElementByClass('hide_chappie')[0].style.display = "inline-block";

            }
```

because function getElementsByClass returns a collection,so you should add [] to find out the result you want!

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of annoying to turn all id's into classes, you can use:

```
function showInfo(){

    document.getElementsByClassName('chappie_info').style.display = "inline-block";
    document.getElementsByClassName('show_chappie').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementsByClassName('hide_chappie').style.display = "inline-block";

}
```

---

This is supported by practically every browser these days so I wouldn't worry about that. If that is still an issue an you need to support ancient browsers, use this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName = function (a) {
    var b = document.getElementsByTagName('*'), i, c=[];
    for (i = 0; i < b.length; i += 1) {  b[i].getAttribute('class')===a&&c.push(b[i]);  }
    return c;
};
```

Comment: that's interesting, but it's alright because I only need to change a few ids. Thanks for your answer though.